# Is there something that's larger than any numbers in PHP?

Tags: php, infinite-value

I need to simulate a ∞ in PHP.

So that `min(∞,$number)` is always `$number`.

Comment: just remove the `min(∞,` and `)` parts ;-)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/fr/math.constants.php . See what you can do with INF constant. Please mark your question as answered ;)

Answer (score 7):

I suppose that, for integers, you could use [`PHP_INT_MAX`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) , the following code :

```
var_dump(PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Gives this output, on my machine :

```
int 2147483647
```

But you have to be careful ; see [Integer overflow](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.overflow) *(quoting)* :

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the
>   bounds of the integer  type, it will
>   be interpreted as a float instead.
>   Also, an operation which results in a
>   number beyond the bounds of the
>   integer type will return a float
>   instead.

And, from the [Floating point numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) documentation page :

> The size of a float is
>   platform-dependent, although a maximum
>   of ~1.8e308 with a precision of
>   roughly 14 decimal digits is a common
>   value (the 64 bit IEEE format).

Considering the integer overflow, and depending on your case, using this kind of value might be a better (?) solution...

Comment: What if $number if larger than 2147483647?

Comment: It will be interpreted as a float, and not an integer (see the portion I quoted about "Integer overflow")

Answer (score 3):

Use the constant `PHP_INT_MAX`.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use the `PHP_INT_MAX` constant [(click for PHP manual docs)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

However, you may want to think about whether you really **need** to use it - it seems like a bit of an odd request.

Answer (score 2):

PHP actually has a predefined constant for "infinity": `INF`. This isn't *true* infinity, but is essentially the largest float value possible. On 64-bit systems, the largest float is **roughly** equal to `1.8e308`, so this is considered to be equal to infinity.

```
$inf = INF;
var_dump(min($inf,PHP_INT_MAX)); // outputs int(9223372036854775807)
var_dump(min($inf,1.79e308)); // outputs float(1.79E+308)
var_dump(min($inf,1.799e308)); // outputs float(INF)
var_dump(min($inf,1.8e308)); // outputs float(INF)
var_dump($inf === 1.8e308); // outputs bool(true)
```

Note, any number with a value larger than the maximum float value will be cast to `INF`. So therefore if we do, `var_dump($inf === 1e50000);`, this will also output `true` even though the maximum float is less than this.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose, assuming this is an integer, you could use PHP_INT_MAX constant.

Answer (score 0):

min($number, $number + 1) ??

Comment: with int overflow $number + 1 could be < $number

Answer (score 0):

In Perl you can use

```
$INF = 9**9E9;
```

which is larger than any value you can store in IEEE floating point numbers. And that really works as intended: any non-infinite number will be smaller than `$INF`:

```
$N < $INF
```

is true for any "normal" number `$N`.

Maybe you use it in PHP too?

Answer (score 0):

`min($number,$number)` is always `$number` (also true for `max()` of course).

Answer (score 0):

If your only concern is comparison function then yes, you can use array(), it will be always larger then any number

like

```
echo min(array(), 9999999999999999);
```

or

```
if (array() > 9999999999999999) {
  echo 'array won';
} else {
  echo 'number won';
}
```